# How does the Apple Watch <-> macOS Sierra unlock feature work in detail?

Tags: bluetooth, macos, apple-watch, unlock

Does anyone know how the Apple Watch unlock feature work in macOS Sierra?

I figured out, that I have to be very near my Mac, that the feature works.

Does it use Bluetooth (BLE) or WIFI?

It would be really nice to get some details about this nice feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It uses both Bluetooth LE 4.0 AND 802.11ac WiFi.

Bluetooth is used to discover the Apple Watch and establish a connection.

Then it uses WiFi to do "time-in-flight" calculations - i.e. to figure out how far your watch is from the Mac. The Mac needs to support 802.11ac WiFi for this to work. All watches are supported, both the old and the new - even though the old ones does not support 802.11ac.

This way it is possible to prevent attacks such as someone planting a "bluetooth repeater" near you, so that it could replay your bluetooth responses captured this way to a Mac located somewhere remotely.

Comment: The timing packets are likely encrypted as well or at least the time stamps are encrypted to prevent playback attacks where someone captures the traffic that unlocked the Mac today at 8 am and then tries to replay it tomorrow when you and your watch are not present.

Comment: The first-generation Apple Watch does not have 802.11ac.

Comment: Does apple provide any official docs?

Comment: You can hear Phil Schiller/Craigh Federighi explain the implementation here: https://vimeo.com/171186055#t=40m15s

Comment: @IronCraftMan That's right - but the Mac that sends the signal needs to have 802.11ac for this to work. The watch that is just receiving the signal does not need to support 802.11ac.

Comment: Also a nice article: https://networkingnerd.net/2016/09/21/apple-watch-unlock-802-11ac-and-time/

Comment: It's really using the 802.11v standard that introduce time of flight stamps. As mentioned by patrickS, the networkingnerd article points that out nicely

Answer (score 5):

I found a interesting article, where this feature is described in detail:

https://networkingnerd.net/2016/09/21/apple-watch-unlock-802-11ac-and-time/

Comment: Pls add details to your article so that it answers the question even if the link is broken or the material in it is changed.

Answer (score 0):

It uses both WIFI.

WIFI checks if your connected to the same network to 'grant you access'.

Comment: If you take a look at https://vimeo.com/171186055#t=40m15s  - Craigh Federighi explains that the distance measurement is done via WiFi - not Bluetooth.

Comment: Would upvote if you update (and I notice)